# Codeigniter: using 'require_once' to call a method of one controller from other

Tags: php, codeigniter, require, require-once

I am finding a way in codeigniter to call a method of one controller to other controller

I find an article like below:

```
1. Controller A 
   class A extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function custom_a()
    {
    }
}

2. Controller B 

   class B extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function custom_b()
    {
            require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/a.php'); //include controller
            $aObj = new a();  //create object 
            $aObj->custom_a(); //call function
    }
}
```

The above code is written by prash.patil in another stack overflow article. But Deep Kakka add a comment: "Include a file like this, Is this good way?"

What is the problem of using 'require_once' in the above said case?  I think it is a good way to reuse code.

Comment: What version of Codeigniter are you running?  I would assume you have an autoloader so you don't need to include/require, you can just call `new A()`.

Comment: Its ok.  I am using the latest version.

But what is the usage?

Make model class first and use autoloader to reuse the code.  Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about using `require_once` with the controller. To fulfil your need
I *suggest you two ways*

1. Use [HMVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) Codeigniter Framework
2. Load Controller as Library

---

**Explain**

1. Use [HMVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) Codeigniter Framework

download the HMVC Framework from [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc). And You can call controller inside the file with `modules::run()` function

2. Load Controller as Library

**Most publicly used method**. Assign controller to the library. and call the methods with the library.

```
# Assigning Controller 
$this->load->library('../controllers/a');

# Calling Methdod

$this->a->methodname();
```

Comment: did you check this ??

Comment: Method 1:  Is it really pure codeigniter?  As I know, codeigniter is only MVC framework

Method 2:  I tried it.  Its not work.

Comment: Ya HMVC is ther. And in.secomd method you hbe to use APPPATH.controller....

Answer (score 0):

If you have set of methods in a class you want to use in multiple controllers, good way would be make a custom library in `APPPATH.'libraries/Custom_lib.php'` (name it what ever you find appropriate) that you could use in any controller where particular code is needed. More about custom libraries in [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html).

Comment: If I make it as a library, why don't we make it as a model?  It's more easy and simple.

Comment: By MVC convention, models are used for database related code. In other hand you can write the code that best suits your needs. If it is some function with small chunk of code, you can make helper that will serve it.